# Adobe Muse - How to add validation checks in a Simple Form?

Tags: muse

I am struggling with adding validation checks, e.g. only allow number input in Adobe Muse text input box. Also, how do you add a dropdown list on the simple contact form, e.g. options are Mr, Mrs, Miss? etcetera.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Muse doesn't have a text attribute for validating text fields. But they do have a number field (https://adobe-muse.github.io/MuCowDocs/#h-number-) which should work for what you are talking about.

And yes, they also have drop-downs (https://adobe-muse.github.io/MuCowDocs/#h-list-).

Hope this helps!